Was Margaret McBride exonerated for the abortion? Or forgiven? Or what?
Not sure I understand what's going on here Excommunication of Margaret McBride. It says



McBride was an administrator and member of the ethics committee at St. Joseph's Hospital and Medical Center, Phoenix, Arizona, which is owned by Catholic Healthcare West, later, Dignity Health On 27 November 2009, the committee was consulted on the case of a 27-year-old woman who was eleven weeks pregnant with her fifth child and suffering from pulmonary hypertension Her doctors stated that the woman's chance of dying if the pregnancy was allowed to continue was "close to 100 percent" McBride joined the ethics committee in approving the decision to terminate the pregnancy through an induced abortion. The abortion took place and the mother survived.




Afterwards, the abortion came to the attention of Bishop Thomas J. Olmsted, the bishop of the Catholic Diocese of Phoenix. Olmsted spoke to McBride privately and she confirmed her participation in the procurement of the abortion. Olmsted informed her that in allowing the abortion, she had incurred a latae sententiae (an automatic) excommunication. McBride was subsequently reassigned from her post as vice president of mission integration at the hospital.




In December 2011, a statement from St. Joseph's Hospital was emailed to the Catholic News Service announcing that McBride had since her excommunication "met the requirements for reinstatement with the church and she is no longer excommunicated. She continues to be a member in good standing with the Sisters of Mercy and is a valued member of the St. Joseph's executive team". The hospital did not provide further details. At the time, McBride was the St. Joseph's Hospital's vice president for organizational outreach.



In particular for the parts

is no longer excommunicated

and

The hospital did not provide further details.

It sounds like they don't confirm which of the following happened:

Forgiven - McBride was wrong but then apologised. McBride was wrong because ______ (fill in the blank as to how an abortion for 'close to 100 percent' death isn't justified?)
Exonerated - McBride was right and then was exonerated meaning McBride's excommunication was like 'annulled' or 'void ab initio' or something.
Other - What happened?


2 is impossible. By her own admission, she was complicit in a procured abortion.

Was Margaret McBride exonerated for the abortion? Or forgiven? Or what?
The very Wikipedia article that you quoted from has the answer.

In November 2011, McBride commented: "So I want you to know that in my journey I did reconcile with the church. The church means something very different to me today. Something has to be taken away sometimes for you to appreciate it even more. So it is now that I believe I am called to do something and I don't know what that something is, but I pray that through the grace of God to give me that opportunity to know what the next step is for me".  - Excommunication of Margaret McBride

If Sister Margaret McBride was indeed reconciled with the Church, it means she confessed her sins within the sacrament of reconciliation.
It could be noted that at this time in Church policy in the United States only the local bishop could lift an excommunication, thus the bishop has to approve a priest confessor to hear her confess and lift the excommunication. In other words, the bishop’s approval is absolutely necessary for the confession for the sin of abortion to be valid.
